# Handle Session in ClassLibrary C#

Tags: c#

I am creating classlibrary project to track the session values.

I don't know how to achieve this, please guide me.

in global.asax file

```
session_Start() //event
{
  obj.Start(string val1,string val2);
 }
```

and

```
session_end()
{
   obj.End();
}
```

in classlibrary project

```
Class Class_Name
{
     public void Start(string val1,string val2)
      {
          guid=Guid.NewGuid(); //for unique id for each session,
          hastable and its values;
           session[guid]=hastable_values;
       }
   public void End()
      {
       hastable t=(hastable)  session[guid]; //here is the problem,its null.

       send the hastable data to database;

      }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: When session end, I need to save the session data to database

Comment: Post a actual example of the issue.

Comment: give me few minutes i will post as images

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused by `Session` and `ApplicationState`.

At the moment the `Session_Start` runs you get a fresh container for that particular browser (due to the session cookie being generated). On every subsequent call the same session container is returned with the objects stored in it for this session. That container is removed when `Session_End` is called.

I'm not sure if `obj` is an instance variable or static variable in both cases your code will behave differently. My suggestion is to keep an instance of the type `Class_Name` in the session with a fixed key. That makes that you can always retrieve that instance and the asp.net framework handles loading the correct unique session container for each request.

```
Session_Start() //event
{
     var cn = new Class_Name();
     cn.Start(string val1,string val2);
     Session["class_name"] = cn;
}

Session_end()
{
    var cn = Session["class_name"] as Class_Name;
    if (cn !=null) 
    {
         cn.End();
    }
}
```

In your classlibrary project and types you can store what ever you want as long as you make sure the types are serializable (in case your instances need to be serialized in a State Server)

```
Class Class_Name
{
     Guid guid;
     HashTable hashtable_values;
     public void Start(string val1,string val2)
     {
          guid=Guid.NewGuid(); //for unique id for each session,
          //hastable and its values;
          // those are now already stored in the session 
     }

     public void End()
     {
        // send the hastable data to database;
        // hash_table has all the values still stored, process them at will
        // do realize that Session_End is not guaranteed to be called
        // so if you still want to store critical stuff in this phase
        // you might be missing data for some sessions    
     }
  }
```

You can bring this logic to your class if you add static factory like methods and an Instance property:

```
class Class_Name
{
    public static void StartSession(string val1, string val2)
    {
        var cn = new Class_Name();
        cn.Start(val1, val2);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["class_name"] = cn;
    }

    // all your classes that need access to theis session object will need 
    // to call this Instance property
    public static Class_Name Instance 
    {
       get 
       {
          return HttpContext.Current.Session["class_name"] as Class_Name;
       }
    }

    public static void EndSession()
    {
        var cn = Instance;
        if (cn != null) 
        {
             cn.End():
        }
    }      
}
```

and your global asax will become:

```
Session_Start() //event
{
     Class_Name.StartSession(string val1,string val2);
}

Session_end()
{
    Class_Name.EndSession();
}
```

Overview of [Application and Page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.100)) on msdn.

Comment: Thanks, Without creating the session variable in global.asax we can not achieve this?

Comment: I've added another way of wiring your class to the Session. @Singaravelan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access session in class used `HttpContext.Current.Session`.[check this link for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpContext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Class Class_Name
{
     public void Start(string val1,string val2)
      {
          guid; //for unique id for each session,
          hastable and its values;
           HttpContext.Current.Session[guid]=hastable_values;
       }
   public void End()
      {
       hastable t=(hastable)  HttpContext.Current.Session[guid]; //here is the problem,its null.

       send the hastable data to database;

      }
  }
```

Comment: in end method, HttpContext.Current.Session[guid] gives null

Comment: @Singaravelan: The session may have been abandoned by the time that event fires.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  What's the underlying goal?

Comment: @Santosh, consider  if multiple users have using then, need to identify the unique id..